# How can I get the url from webview when page redirects? (This is in a functional component not class)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

This is my functional component

```
const MyScreen = (props) => {

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <WebView
        source={{uri: `${Helpers.URL}`}}
        javaScriptEnabled={true} //enabling JavaScript
        javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
        onMessage={event => {
        }}
        onLoadStart={() => {
          console.log("LOAD START ");
        }}
        onLoadEnd={() => {

        }}
        onError={err => {
          console.log('ERROR ');
          console.log(err);
        }}
        onNavigationStateChange = {() => {
          console.log('State changed...');
          // TODO: check what the url is at this point
        }}

      />
    </Wrapper>

  )
}
```

I'd like to be able to get the url of the newly loaded page.

Comment: `<WebView
       ref="webview"
       source={{uri}}
       onNavigationStateChange={(e) => handleNavigationStateChange(e)}
       javaScriptEnabled = {true}
       domStorageEnabled = {true}
       injectedJavaScript = {cookie}
       startInLoadingState={false}
     />`

Comment: @AlfredAyi-bonte I found a snack that I converted from a class component to a functional one that did the job for me. https://snack.expo.io/H1idX8vpM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
const MyScreen = (props) => {


  handleNavigationStateChange = navState => {
    // This gets us the navstate which has the url of the newly loaded page
    console.log(navState);
  };


  const url = `${Helpers.URL}`

  // this javascript will be injected on page load 
  const injectedJs = `
  window.postMessage(window.location.href);
`;


  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: url }}
      bounces={true}
      style={[
        {
          flex: 1
        },
      ]}
      injectedJavaScript={injectedJs}
      startInLoadingState
      scalesPageToFit
      javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      onNavigationStateChange={this.handleNavigationStateChange}
      onMessage={event => {
        alert('MESSAGE >>>>' + event.nativeEvent.data);
      }}
      onLoadStart={() => {
        console.log("LOAD START ");
      }}
      onLoadEnd={() => {
        console.log('LOAD END');
      }}
      onError={err => {
        console.log('ERROR ');
        console.log(err);
      }}
    />
  )
}
```